# Images in Svg.JS Disappear After Animating Them

Tags: javascript, animation, svg.js

I am using SVG.js to make some simple animations.

First, I create a group of images:

```
let movingPassengers = draw.group()
for (let id of IDs) {
    movingPassengers.add(drawings.get(id))
}
//drawings is a Map object, each entry in the map contains something like this:
draw.image(assetsDirectory + currentPassenger.type + '.svg')
//draw is the following object:
SVG('animation-container')
```

then, I animate it with the following:

```
movingPassengers.animate(animationTime, '<>', 0).move(endXCoord, 0)
```

However, after the images finish moving, they disappear. How can I prevent the images from disappearing?

Here is an example - notice how the farmer and wolf are gone from the screen. 
[image: Moving_Screenshot]

Comment: it would be easier if you added a fiddle link or something - or at least provide the full code - see this is working https://jsfiddle.net/49hfk2bq/ so it must be something wrong with something else in your code

Comment: I found out the problem - after finishing the animation I tried to move the individual elements in the group. This caused them to disappear. It seems like I need to first remove the group before manipulating the individual elements.